# Multiple conditional operation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is consists of six columns.

```
   station phase  tr_time     long2      lat2    distance
0      CET    ES    54.92  71.91500  33.82850  184.154595
1      CET    EP    32.82  71.91500  33.82850  184.154595
2      DHL    ES    41.32  72.32200  33.16267  129.915158
3      DHL    EP    25.85  72.32200  33.16267  129.915158
4      FAG    ES    37.83  72.57900  33.61317  118.384655
5      FAG    EP    22.69  72.57900  33.61317  118.384655
6      MUR    ES    28.66  73.44883  33.83300   81.700593
7      MUR    EP    16.18  73.44883  33.83300   81.700593
8      NBB    ES    62.30  71.52967  33.15267  203.678122
9      NBB    EP    35.44  71.52967  33.15267  203.678122
10     NIL    ES    25.29  73.25167  33.64967   71.858579
11     NLB    EP    15.30  73.27017  33.65167   71.019778
12     NLB    ES    26.03  73.27017  33.65167   71.019778
13     NPR    EP    17.00  73.14017  33.75200   87.171555
14     NPR    ES    29.50  73.14017  33.75200   87.171555
15     PAL    EP    23.46  72.46550  32.63183  129.494794
16     PAL    ES    40.58  72.46550  32.63183  129.494794
```

I need to perform the subtraction operation under the following conditions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in df['station']:
    if [((df['phase']=='ES') & (df['tr_time']=S_t)) &
            ((df['phase']=='EP') & (df['tr_time']=P_t))]:
        B=S_t - P_t
        print(B, P_t)
```

(Explanation: If for the same station we have both phases (`EP` and `ES`), we need to subtract the `tr_time` corresponding to each phase(`B=ES (tr_time)-EP/(tr_time`) and print both (`EP`, `B`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can group by station name and make a iteration for every resulting dataframe. After these, you may check that the two phases that you need exist and finally make the subtraction:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
stations = df.groupby("station")
answers = {}
for name, df_station in stations:
    phases = df_station['phase'].to_list()
    if 'ES' in phases and 'EP' in phases:
        answers[name] = df_station.loc[df_station['phase'] =='ES']['tr_time'].item() - df_station.loc[df_station['phase'] == 'EP']['tr_time'].item()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in df['station']:
    if ((df['phase'] == 'ES') & (df['tr_time'] == S_t)) & ((df['phase'] =='EP') & (df['tr_time'] == P_t)):
        B = S_t - P_t
        print(B, P_t)
```

Just change "=" to "==".

Comment: I did but this line (df['tr_time'] == S_t) is not working maybe because tr-time is float

Comment: You can multiply to 100 if you are not asking the best solution! (100 *df["tr_time"] == 100 * S_t)